# On a computation of probability generating function

Tags: probability, generating-functions, formal-power-series

Let $X$ be a discrete random variable taking only non-negative integer values . Let $f(s):=\sum_{n=0}^\infty P(X=n)s^n$

(think of the sum formally, and indeed it absolutely converges for $|s|<1)$ .

Then how do we write $g(s)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty P(X=2n)s^n$ in terms of $f$ ?

I know that $\sum _{n=0}^\infty P(X>n)s^n=\dfrac {1-f(s)}{1-s}$ for $|s|<1$, but I don't know whether it is useful or not .

Please help . Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you know $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \mathsf P(X>n)s^n=\frac{1-p(s)}{1-s}$?

Comment: @GrahamKemp : It is just straightforward manipulation of $(1-s)\sum_{n=0}^\infty P(X>n)s^n$

Comment: There is nothing straightforward about that.  Where did $p(s)$ come from?

Comment: @GrahamKemp : I meant $f$

Comment: And why do you think $(1-s)\sum_{n=0}^\infty \mathsf P(X>n) s^n = 1-\sum_{n=0}^\infty \mathsf P(X=n)s^n$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot write $g(\cdot)$ in terms of $f(\cdot)$ alone unless you know more about the distribution of $X$.

However $\lower{3.5ex}{\begin{split}g(s^{2}) &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \mathsf P(X=2n) s^{2n} \\ &= f(s)-\sum_{n=0}^\infty \mathsf P(X=2n+1)s^{2n+1}\end{split}}$

Comment: How can you so surely say we cannot write $g$ in terms of $f$ alone ?

Comment: $f(s)=g(s^2)+h(s^2)$ where $h$ is similar to, but not quite, $g$.$$\begin{split}g(s^2)&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\mathsf P(X=2n)s^{2n}\\h(s^2)&=s\, \sum_{n=0}^\infty \mathsf P(X=2n+1)s^{2n}\end{split}$$So we at least need to know more about the distribution of $X$ to find a way express $h$ in terms of $g$.